# @@trancount value is 1 in stored procedure without begin tran

Tags: sql-server

I have following definition of stored procedure:

```
CREATE procedure dbo.ImportData
 (                
     @SessionId VARCHAR(20)
    ,@ImportId      int
) 

as 

begin
 PRINT 'TRANCOUNT value = ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS VARCHAR)
begin try

--business log

begin try
BEGIN CATCH

--business log

END CATCH
END
```

Whenever i am running my SP, i am getting @@Trancount value as 1 however i have not begin any transaction using BEGIN TRAN statement.

Please suggest this behavior of sql server of creating a transition after BEGIN statement of the SP definition.

Also, when i tried to replicate the same behavior by creating another SP without parameter and only one SELECT statement but i am getting Transition value as 0.

Please suggest this concept.

Comment: how do you run your SP?

Comment: Hi Backs, i am using EXEC commad to run SP, like this EXEC dbo.ImportData

Comment: my only guess - you have already opened transaction (maybe accidentally). try do disconnect from sql-server

Comment: Thanks Backs, I think my initial run had left some open transition. I tried after reconnecting my server as suggested and it worked fined.

Comment: glad to know! be careful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already opened transaction (maybe accidentally). 
Try to disconnect from sql-server or commit (rollbcack) existing transactions.